# How to convert an audio file to text using IBM's Watson Speech to Text service

Tags: python, ibm-watson

I ran this code:

```
import json
import os
import sys
from watson_developer_cloud import SpeechToTextV1

def transcribe_audio(audio_file_name) :
    IBM_USERNAME = "apikey"
    IBM_PASSWORD = "Password"
    stt = SpeechToTextV1(username=IBM_USERNAME, password=IBM_PASSWORD)
    audio_file = open(audio_file_name, "rb")        
    json_file = os.path.abspath("audio")+".json"; 
    with open(json_file, 'w') as fp:
        result = stt.recognize(audio_file,timestamps=True, content_type='audio/wav', inactivity_timeout =-1,word_confidence = True)
        json.dump(result, fp, indent=2)
    script = "Script is : "
    for rows in result['results']:
        script += rows['alternatives'][0]['transcript']
    #print(script);

transcribe_audio("audio.wav")
```

And I got this error:

```
Object of type 'DetailedResponse' is not JSON serializable
```

I tried to just print the text from the audio file, that didn't work either.
I'm just trying to get the text.

Comment: I assume the error was from the `json.dump`? What was the error when you tried printing `result`?

Comment: `get_result()` on `stt.recognize(...)` will likely fix it: `stt.recognize(..).get_result()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good sample [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/blob/master/examples/speech_to_text_v1.py). Look like you are missing `get_result()` on the `stt.recognize()` call.